# How to make particle instances the same size as the dupli object?

Tags: objects, particles, transforms

If I create an object and assign it as the dupli object of a hair particle system on another object, the size of the particles is much smaller than that of the actual dupli object.  I then have to change the *length* to compensate.  How can I make the particles "life size"?

Here is an example, the big box is used as the dupli object for the particle on the plane.  All particle settings are left as default except *type: hair*, *number: 100*, and *render > object: `Cube`*.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely forgot that there are actually two separate values which affect the size of the particles.  There is the hair *length* (found at the top of the settings), but there is also a *size* spinner under the *physics* rollout.

[image]

It turns out that the actual size of the particles is the *product* of these two values.  I.e. `actual_size = length * size`.  So if both these values are set to `1` the particles will be the same size as the dupli object.

The *size* defaults to `0.05`, while *length* defaults to `4`, so the actual size of the particles by default is `0.05 * 4 = 0.2`, which is one fifth the dupli object's size.

I have no idea why there are two separate values which control particle size, or why one of them is under the *physics* rollout, or why they have such strange default values.  If someone could explain this I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I found this in blender 2.83 in Render > Scale. Hair length must be 1 too