# Vertex coordinate monitoring during Transform

Tags: vertices, snapping

Is it possible, for example, to monitor the coordinates of a vertex while rotating the mesh? (monitored vertex is moving in a circular fashion, providing it's not on the global/local rotation axis)

I'm looking into this as a possible solution to [a snapping problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118827/snapping-vertices-in-a-particle-system)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: There's no question mark, but it's clear that I'm asking if there's a way of monitoring the coordinates of a singular vertex making up a mesh, while the mesh is going through a transform (in the same way the mesh origin is monitored and the coordinates are visible in the right tab)

Comment: In the Properties Region > Transform panel, when in Edit Mode, you can read/set the position of single vertex, or the median position of a set of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bring a vertex of one mesh to a particular vertex of another mesh do this:

- select the first object, switch to edit mode, deselect all vertices and select the one to which you want to bring the other vertex.
- Switch to object mode
- Similarly select the other object and repeat the above steps to selecting the node you want to be moved
- Execute the following script replacing the name 'Cube1' with the reference object and 'Cube2' with the object whose vertex you want to move:

  ```
  import bpy
  obj1 = bpy.data.objects['Cube1'] 
  obj2 = bpy.data.objects['Cube2'] 
  co = obj1.matrix_world * [v for v in obj1.data.vertices if v.select == True][0].co
  [v for v in obj2.data.vertices if v.select == True][0].co = obj2.matrix_world.inverted() * co
  ```

  [image]

Comment: I want the transform of the whole mesh to conform to the future destination of one of the mesh vertices, when the mesh origin is static or otherwise.

Comment: there's a more specific problem in the link, which could be solved if one of the highlighted polar vertex coordinates could be monitored.

Comment: I could make a similar scene using DupliVerts but I don't know how to rotate the duplicates so they're pointing to the center.