# Is there a Delta version of "Selection to Cursor" to set the coordinates of "delta transform"?

Tags: animation, transforms

This question is related to manual construction of [Tetrix fractal Tree](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143273/how-to-create-a-tetrix-sierpinski-tetrahedron-fractal-radiating-from-0-0-0-pyt/143390) animation.

[Delta transform demonstration](https://youtube.com/watch?v=ZAq4BTpfQn8)