# AN: Platonic Solid Fractal Maker

Tags: animation-nodes

I have this node setup in animation nodes :
[image: tree1]
and am trying to make this object:[image: cube]

What I want is to be able to take one of those "iteration" boxes and loop it.  But when I try to do it, I get this problem:
[image]

Also, when I connect the object list of the Invoke Subprogram node to the Object socket on the Loop Input, it keeps creating a Create Object List node, which is useless for what i'm trying to do.

Is there another way to do this that keeps the Object Instancer out of the loop?

I want to be able to animate the number of iterations, as well as have the Scale value of the Object Transforms Output node reduce with each iteration by a factor of *n*, which I will also animate.

Is this possible in AN?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143273/how-to-create-a-tetrix-sierpinski-tetrahedron-fractal-radiating-from-0-0-0-pyt/144493#144493

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in AN, but I believe you need to put the Object instancer out side of the loop; this instancer is used to crerate the list of objects; you use the loop to iterate through the list of objects.