# Speed up bpy object creation with "for loop"

Tags: python, scripting

so i'm fairly new to blender scripting and could need some advice with this:

To put it simply, I want to create a cube made up of smaller cubes (100x100x100) with this script:

```
N=100;
for i in range(0,N,3):   
   for j in range(0,N,3):   
      for k in range(0,N,3):
          bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_editmode=True, location=(i,j,k))
```

which works well with smaller N. But takes horribly long with larger N. In the code above there are over 9000 objects to be created so I can assume there is a lot of memory to be allocated which slows things down.

However, I there a way to create such objects much faster? Is there a fundamental problem with my approach that I've not seen yet?

I also experience this "slow" behavior in other scripting modellers like OpensScad and hoped maybe blender does this a little better.

Tips and advice very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You should usually try to make identical objects as instances. They share data and renders faster. You could do that with Duplicate Linked, Particles or instancing per verts or faces (object properties).

Answer (score 1):

**Using array modifier**

Using array modifiers will speed up the processing because it will lower the overall io between Blender and Python and also lower bpy.ops usage:

Create a base cube object.

Create and apply three array modifiers on it.

The code is commented below, but if not clear enough, please ask in the comments.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

def apply_modifier( obj, count, vector ):
    # Add an array modifier with its wanted parameters
    m = obj.modifiers.new( name = "Array", type = 'ARRAY' )
    m.use_relative_offset = False
    m.use_constant_offset = True
    m.constant_offset_displace = vector
    m.count = count
    # Apply it
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply( modifier = m.name )

def create_base_cube( context, name, size ):
    # Create an object
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new( name )
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new( name, mesh )

    # Add a cube
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh( mesh )
    bmesh.ops.create_cube( bm, size = size, calc_uvs = False )
    bm.to_mesh( mesh )
    bm.free()

    # Link the object to the scene and set it active
    context.scene.collection.objects.link( obj )
    context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

    return obj

name = "CubeMap"
size = 2

obj = create_base_cube( bpy.context, name, size )

N=100;
interval = 3

apply_modifier( obj, N, (interval, 0, 0) )
apply_modifier( obj, N, (0, interval, 0) )
apply_modifier( obj, N, (0, 0, interval) )
```

**Using dupliverts** (proposed by [Jackdaw](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/67624/jackdaw) in the comments)

An alternative is to use dupliverts, which seems to be faster and allows to define any patterns (not only cubic).

The principle is to create an object with vertices at the positions you want, then make it parent to a cube and use dupliverts as instancing method.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from itertools import product

def create_base_cube( context, name, size ):
    # Create an object
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new( name )
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new( name, mesh )

    # Add a cube
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh( mesh )
    bmesh.ops.create_cube( bm, size = size, calc_uvs = False )
    bm.to_mesh( mesh )
    bm.free()

    # Link the object to the scene and set it active
    context.scene.collection.objects.link( obj )
    context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

    return obj

def make_result_object( context, name, cube, vertices ):
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new( name )
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new( name, mesh )

    # Associate the vertices
    obj.data.from_pydata( vertices, [], [] )

    # Link the object to the scene and set it active
    context.scene.collection.objects.link( obj )
    context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

    # Make the object parent of the cube
    cube.parent = obj
    # Make the object dupliverts
    obj.instance_type = 'VERTS'

    return obj

name = "CubeMap"
size = 2

cube = create_base_cube( bpy.context, name, size )

N=3*100
interval = 3

vertices = [(x, y, z) for x, y, z in product( range(0,N,interval), range(0,N,interval), range(0,N,interval) )]

result = make_result_object( bpy.context, "result", cube, vertices )
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I haven't thought about modifiers, so that solution could actually work quite efficiently. However, how would you proceed if the actual object I want to create in my loops depends on a condition? E.g. I read external data and depending on them i create a sphere instead of a cube with 100x100x100 objects. Is there a way to make such conditional array modifiers?

Comment: Jackdaw's proposal with duplicate Linked might work here. I will have a look at both of your solutions. Thanks so much for the input

Comment: @Lilly2015, Python will have some limits here. 100x100x100 will create 8 millions vertices for cubes. But another method could be using dupliverts: make a mesh with only vertices (a big sphere for instance) then use dupliverts on it to fill it with cubes. That what I've used in the script here (second part of the answer): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143273/how-to-create-a-tetrix-sierpinski-tetrahedron-fractal-radiating-from-0-0-0-pyt/144493#144493 . Anyway, the less is done using Python, the faster it is

Comment: @Lilly2015, have added a duplivert version (faster it seems)