# How do you create a triangle pattern in a plane?

Tags: geometry

[image: this]
I want to create this picture, except going on for the entire plane, and just the geometry, not with multiple shapes. Is there a way to do this? (not with the going over lines)

Comment: Hello :). Do you mean a triangulated plane or a texture? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I meant the geometry of the plane, so if I moved a vert and had proportional editing on, the surface would be a lot of triangles like a hill

Comment: Perhaps related: [How do I stack triangles into a bigger triangle with array modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/187180/78972)

Comment: no, like the triangles are in the plane without anything changing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to add to Markus von Broady's answer:

1. Shear the result by -0,5
2. Scale by √75 (0,8660254...)
3. Done

Tadaa...

[image]

Comment: wait but its not equilateral help!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sIGZqaz

Comment: Might've missed something, but the triangles come equilateral at my end :).

Comment: can i have the blend please :)

Comment: Or you could rotate an edge 60°, make a face and subdivide that :) https://i.imgur.com/JHHxkpW.gif

Comment: @Markus Now that's just stupidly simple. Or add a circle with 3 sides. Aaargh...  :D

Comment: oh i am so bad at blender

Comment: Instead of typing `0.8660254` into the y-scale filed, just type `sqrt(0.75)`. Blender will evaluate simple Python expressions like that for you :)

Comment: @maddin45 Thanks, i'll edit it in :). Tried it with the √ symbol before, but Blender got confused :).

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way I can think of is to divide a plane into 2 triangles first (e.g. select opposite corner vertices and press <kbd>J</kbd>), then select both and subdivide.

[image]

You can also use *Subdivision Surface* + *Triangulate* modifiers:

[image]

Comment: This is probably the closest you will get to triangles. In the picture you shared, a square is impossible, so it will never fit the mesh right.

Comment: What about a hexagon plane?

Comment: @Clobro I don't have time for a full answer but: add a circle with 6 sides, in edit mode, extrude but don't move vertices. scale to 0 and weld, you now have one hexagon. Use the array modifier to make as many as you need.

Comment: "poke faces" :)