# How can I create a pill shaped plane?

Tags: vertices, bevel

I want to create a pill shaped plane from the plane seen in the picture.

[image: plane with four points]

When I use the bevel tool (affect vertices) I always get an ellipse shaped plane. How can I create a pill shaped plane?

My goal is to create this shape:

[image: desired shape]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: it should work fine with bevels, you can get half circles on each tip

Comment: If you get an elliptical plane I suspect you've started with a square plane which you scaled in one direction in _Object Mode_ without applying the scale. If you would have applied it or scaled the plane in _Edit Mode_, your method should have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also possible with a plane:

[image]

If you select to vertices, press CTRL-B to bevel, scroll up to increase the segments, press V and move your mouse like this:

Comment: Reminds me of https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216199/60486 ... There's always a simpler way :D

Comment: LOL ;) so never start your answer with "the simplest way i can...." ;)

Comment: This is what the OP did - your example just works because you don't scale the plane in _Object Mode_. You should mention that, otherwise yellowcab will always get a wrong result when trying to bevel non-square planes.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann : If this is what he did, why did he give me the „correct answer“ check? So I would say: your assumption was wrong…

Comment: @Chris Well, that's something you should ask the OP. The question literally reads "When I use the bevel tool (affect vertices) I always get an ellipse shaped plane." Your answer is use the bevel tool and press V (which is affecting the vertices), so it is the same. Getting uneven bevel offsets because of an unapplied scale is a problem which is asked here dozens of times and fits to his description. Why it didn't work if my assumption was wrong and what is now different to mark your answer accepted is clearly lacking clarification from the OP's side. Maybe it was intuition to apply the scale?

Answer (score 2):

The gist of it is pretty simple: Create a circle, select half of it, <kbd>Y</kbd> rip it, move it, reconnect it, <kbd>A</kbd> select all and <kbd>F</kbd> create a face.

[image]

The rest is a problem of how to make the angles symmetric; in order to not have to figure the rotation of the circle, I'd recommend to first rotate the reference image so the pill is positioned horizontally or vertically. Another problem may be how to achieve correct topology, but in your case it seems you will be fine with <kbd>I</kbd> insetting the face and then <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> removing the inner face.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right way. Here are detailed instructions on how you do it:

1. This step is a very important one because it's the reason why your bevel didn't work as expected. When you've stretched the plane in *Object Mode*, it is not evenly scaled in all directions, in my example the scale is 1 for X and Z, but 2.5 for Y. To make them all equal without shortening the plane again you have to **apply the scale**. To do that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Apply* > *Scale* (to avoid this you should have scaled the plane in *Edit Mode*).

[image: apply scale]

2. Next comes what you already did. In *Edit Mode*, select the vertices, then activate the *Bevel Tool* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Hit <kbd>V</kbd> to *Affect Vertices* and also <kbd>C</kbd> to *Clamp Overlap*. This way you can bevel to the maximum until the vertices of the opposing bevels meet at the center and don't overlap this distance. Now you have beveled both sides to half-circles.

[image: beveling]

3. The only thing which might cause problems with modeling further is that where the bevels met there are now two vertices in the same location. To merge them together just hit <kbd>A</kbd> to *Select All*, then press <kbd>M</kbd> to *Merge* > *By Distance*. This will get rid of the doubled vertices.

[image: merge by distance]