# Remove edges from inner side of sphere

Tags: modeling, animation, edges

I have an animation with 2 half spheres in blender that I need to export in web. However, before exporting, I tried to smoothen the edges with subdivision modifier. It worked with one half but the inner side of another half has these edges which I can't remove[image: the problem]

It wasn't me who created this animation so I don't really know what might cause this and how to fix it.

Please help!

Comment: can you share that file? Because I am not really sure what do you mean by "I can't remove" is there some error message or anything?

Comment: Yes, here is the link to the file https://xfl.jp/fdVP7y. I have no experience in working with blender, from tutorials I understood that it can be made in edit mode, but I can't select those lines.

Comment: of course you cannot remove them, you have active subdivision modifier... you first need to either apply it and then remove those edges or remove modifier

Comment: Ok I think I got it, I know it was a dumb question, but thank you very much for clearing this for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're more or less in the above situation, with one ngon face as a slide:

On the left, the shape before subdivision, one the right, after subdivision:

[image]

The subdivision extends faces and in consequence some blue part are going over what was orange before.

To correct it, you need to modify the inner mesh (in edit mode):

A first possibility is to select the face and bevel its edges using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. But the orange part will go outside a bit.

[image]

A second possibility, is to remake the face:

Delete it, select the edge, extrude and scale 0 (<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>).

[image]

Assign it back the orange material, add a loop cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) and push it near the edge.

[image]

and finally, select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and merge (<kbd>M</kbd>) by distance.

Comment: The first option worked like a charm! Thank you so much

Comment: If you bevel with 2 segments, (profile, say, 0).. then you can reassign the material on one side, if necessary, and the result is sharp.

Comment: @RobinBetts, the good man at the good moment ! do you think that's possible with GN as it is for now? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144493/19156 (and yes I know about bevel...)

Comment: @lemon    hehe ... comment aimed at OP, don't worry.. :) Serpinsky?  Absolutely possible in GN, at first sight.. except for parameter-izing iterations, without loops or recursion?

Comment: @RobinBetts, yes no loops afaik... maybe impossible so (or headache)?

Comment: @lemon ... [the basic form](https://imgur.com/a/Oyz7Jt6) is pretty simple, but I guess we're looking for animation, varying levels ..

Comment: @RobinBetts, yes animation... not hard coded like in your example. (how to go to chat for talking about that?)