# Vertex at curve/circle intersect

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, vertices

[image]
I haven't found out how do things in Blender that can be done i Geogebra for ex.,
Lets say I want to make a circle and then make more circles that have centers somewhere on the circumference, or a freehand/random version of what's in the picture.
Im my experience the vertex can't/doesn't appear where I want it to be, IT already has to be there. 
Vertice count set manually at object creation or using tools.
Precise constructions that develop from one another and rely on unforeseen intersections are impossible to make under these conditions,
which is why I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Is there a way to do this even though it's not apparent to me ?

The thing called a "circle" in the Mesh menu I feel should be called an n-gon, since it doesn't act like a circle, as far as I can tell.
(based on the IDEA of what a circle is, AN infinite amount of vertices)

Comment: Maybe that can be obtained using animation nodes and starting from two Bezier circles as they are not ngons.